# Does RTMP support the Display Orientation SEI Message in h264 streams?

Tags: android, video-streaming, h.264, rtmp

I'm streaming video h264 video and AAC audio over RTMP on Android using the native MediaCodec APIs. Video and audio look great, however while the video is shot in potrait mode, playback on the web or with VLC is always in landscape.

Having read through the h264 spec, I see that this sort of extra metadata can be specified in Supplemental Enhancement Information (SEI), and I've gone about adding it to the raw h264 bit stream. My SEI NAL unit for this follows this rudimentary format, I plan to optimize later:

```
val displayOrientationSEI = {
    val prefix = byteArrayOf(0, 0, 0, 1)
    val nalHeader = byteArrayOf(6) // forbidden_zero_bit:0; nal_ref_idc:0; nal_unit_type:6 

    val display = byteArrayOf(47 /* Display orientation type*/, 3 /*payload size*/)

    val displayOrientationCancelFlag = "0" // u(1); Rotation information follows
    val horFlip = "1" // hor_flip; u(1); Flip horizontally
    val verFlip = "1" // ver_flip; u(1); Flip vertically
    val anticlockwiseRotation = "0100000000000000" // u(16); value / 2^16 -> 90 degrees
    val displayOrientationRepetitionPeriod = "010" // ue(v); Persistent till next video sequence
    val displayOrientationExtensionFlag = "0" // u(1); No other value is permitted by the spec atm
    val byteAlignment = "1"

    val bitString = displayOrientationCancelFlag +
            horFlip +
            verFlip +
            anticlockwiseRotation +
            displayOrientationRepetitionPeriod +
            displayOrientationExtensionFlag +
            byteAlignment

    prefix + nalHeader + display + BigInteger(bitString, 2).toByteArray()
}()
```

Using [Jcodec's SEI class](https://github.com/jcodec/jcodec/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jcodec/codecs/h264/io/model/SEI.java), I can see that my SEI message is parsed properly. I write out these packets to the RTMP stream using an [Android JNI wrapper for LibRtmp](https://github.com/ant-media/LibRtmp-Client-for-Android).

Despite this, ffprobe does not show the orientation metadata, and the video when played remains in landscape.

At this point I think I'm missing a very small detail about how FLV headers work when the raw h264 units are written out by LibRtmp. I have tried appending this `displayOrientationSEI` NAL unit:

1. To the initial SPS and PPS configuration only.
2. To each raw h264 NAL units straight from the encoder.
3. To both.

What am I doing wrong? Going through the source of some RTMP libraries, like [rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java](https://github.com/pedroSG94/rtmp-rtsp-stream-client-java), it seems the SEI message is dropped when creating FLV tags.

Help is much, much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does RTMP support the Display Orientation SEI Message in h264 streams?

RTMP is unaware of the very concept. from RTMPs perspective, the SEI is just a series of bytes it copys. It never looks at them, it never parses them.

The thing that needs to support it, is the h.264 decoder (which RTMP is also unaware of) and the player software. If it is not working for you, you must check the player, or the validity of the encoded SEI, not the transport.

Comment: Gotcha, thank you. It appears the library that muxes the raw h264 and AAC units to FLV for RTMP strips the SEI for whatever reason. Given your specialty, have you by any chance sent the Display Orientation SEI over RMTP before? Going through the source for two RTMP muxing libraries for Android, they both opt to drop the SEI and manually rotate the video frames before sending them out. Wondering if this is bc they were written before the Display Orientation SEI was added.

Comment: I see now my question title is wrong. What I meant is does the FLV container format, especially that used to stream over RTMP, support encoding the SEI messages from h264 videos it muxes? Library implementations I've seen just seem to only keep the NAL unit types SPS, PPS, IDR and NonIDR; the remaining are just ignored for whatever reason.

Comment: Again FLV has no concept of SEI. There is noting in the spec. Flv just wraps the es.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, and yes, I get that. What I'm trying to ask, albeit horribly is, I have raw h264 NAL units that have associated SEI. I'm muxing them with AAC NAL Units with a 3rd party library into an FLV container to send over RTMP. This muxer invariably drops the SEI NAL units when muxing, only sending the NAL types in the previous comment. My question is am I going about things the wrong way, or is the library dropping this deliberately because of some FLV container limitation I'm unaware of? Just saw your last edit, the container just wraps, I'll debug the lib a bit more. ty

Comment: There is no FLV container limitation. And a library should not change that.  I don’t know anything about the library you are using,  or do I even know WHAT library you are using.

Comment: I really appreciate your taking the time out for answering me. I'm using a JNI wrapper around LibRTMP for Android: https://github.com/ant-media/LibRtmp-Client-for-Android/blob/master/rtmp-client/src/main/cpp/flvmuxer/xiecc_rtmp.c. Specifically the rtmp_sender_write_video_frame method. That source file is where I see it only writing certain NAL types.

Comment: Looking through the code, that library will also corrupt streams with B frames. It’s garbage code, don’t use it.

Comment: One last ping @szatmary. I'm trying to fix the muxing implementation in that library so I don't have to build from scratch. The FLV spec for specifies a FrameType for Video Tags as seen on page 9 here.
https://www.adobe.com/content/dam/acom/en/devnet/flv/video_file_format_spec_v10.pdf

1 for key frames (seekable) which I would think map to IDR frames for h264, 2 for non key frames which would cover NAL unit types 1 - 4. All these are VCL NAL Units. Where would SEI, a non-VCL unit fall into?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215045/discussion-between-tunji-d-and-szatmary).

Comment: If you have a new question, make a new post.